# webpack to bundle code targeting node.js

Tags: node.js, webpack

I use `webpack` for bundling the client side and want to use it for building node/npm library. I saw I can specify the target as `node` for this. From the [doc](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html),

```
"node" Compile for usage in a node.js-like environment (use require to load chunks)
```

But the problem is `react.js` is bundled in the compile output. I want only my source files and any dependencies listed in `package.json` to be included. I have specified react as peerDependency, like

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=0.13",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": ">=0.1.3"
  },
```

I also try defining react in `externals` expecting it may just create the symbol and not include the library itself, but it still includes `react` in compiled output.

```
 target: "node",
    externals: [{
        'react' : 'React',
    }]
```

so, is there a way to use `webpack` to bundle by server side / node code, but also to specify not to bundle some of the dependencies (which may be defined as `peerDependencies` or `devDependencies`)?

Comment: In you `webpack.config.js` add `target: 'node'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

James had written a 3 part series on it.

http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I

following his code, `externals` were set as

```
{ 'babel-core': 'commonjs babel-core',
  'babel-loader': 'commonjs babel-loader',
  classnames: 'commonjs classnames',
  react: 'commonjs react',
...
}
```

which worked great.

Comment: This isn't necessary anymore. As mentioned by @rubens-mariuzzo, a simple "target: 'node'" in your webpack.config.js should do the trick.